# Display Images with Different Height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So, I'm trying to do a **list** with images, with **different height**, like this:

```
 _______   _______
| IMG1  | | IMG4  |
|_______| |       |
 _______  |       |
| IMG2  | |       |
|       | |_______|
|_______|  _______
 _______  | IMG5  |
| IMG3  | |       |
|       | |_______|
|       |  _______
|       | | IMG6  |
|_______| |_______|
```

And the people can scroll. I thought about using `TableView`, but the `UITableViewCell` must have a fixed height. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have fixed 6 image of fix size,then i suggest to use six uiimageview of whatever size you want place in scroll view, and then set image programmatically.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` supports cells of varying heights, via the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method of its delegate.  But if you want two columns of images, where all the images are different heights, you'll need to use `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Sure, sure. What I was trying to say is that the UITableView don't allow to have the first line with 82px, and the second with 12 (Example). I'll try to use UIScrollView. ;-)

Comment: `UITableView` does allow different cell heights. You have to return the height in the delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I suspect he means that the cell must be a rectangle - its top and bottom edges must be horizontal.